# How Do I delete a remap from .ideavim?

Tags: ideavim

Am using intelij and Ideavim.
I remapped Esc to `gh` by typing `inoremap gh <Esc>` in `.ideavimrc` and its been working fine. Recently, I found out that while typing a word like "Hi`gh`light", the `gh` inbetween will always be read as `gh` and then vim will move out of insert mode.

I've tried to revert it by deleting the content in `.ideavim` but the old `gh` is still working.
I've also tried changing it to `gg` and then to `jj` in an attempt to may be erase the old `gh`, but they seem to be pilling up.

When I type in :imap, I see this [image]

And all three of them, `gg`, `gh`, and `jj` are all working as Esc when in insert mode.

How do I get rid of the rest and leave only `jj`?

I've also tried a lot of suggestions, like using iumap or umap but it doesn't seem to be working.
Am on windows.

Comment: Have you restarted Intellij after changing the configuration file?

Comment: Yes. A couple of times but they are still there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was `imapclear`. This cleared all the previous remaps I made.
Note, it will clear only the remaps that are effective in insert mode only.
Here is a very usefully resource that helped me https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_(Part_1)